# Segfault when i want to access a double pointer

Tags: pointers, segmentation-fault

```c
int main(void)
{
    char **lol;
    
    lol = malloc(100);
    *lol = malloc(100);
    *lol[42] = 'd';
    printf("%c", *lol[42]);
    return (0);
}
```

can someone tell me why it segfault ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR:

```
lol = malloc(100);
*lol = malloc(100);
```

This is *A Bad Thing*<sup>TM</sup>. Do this instead

```
lol = malloc(100*sizeof*lol);
*lol = malloc(100*sizeof(**lol));
```

---

`char` is a character and `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1.

`char*` on the other hand is a pointer to a `char` and so `sizeof(char*)` depends on your system. Pointers are *usually* 4 bytes on 32-bit systems and 8 bytes on 64-bit systems.

Why do we care about the size of `char`, `char*`? Because `malloc`s arguments are in terms of **bytes** not in terms of elements. So when you do:

```
lol = malloc(100);
```

You are allocating 100 **bytes** in memory, but since `lol` is a pointer this actually only accounts for 100/4 = 25 `char*` pointers on 32-bit systems and 100/8 = 12.5 `char*` on 64-bit systems.

Now I haven't verified this myself, but according to [this handy tool](https://byjus.com/greater-than-calculator/) 42 seems to be larger than 25 and 12.5 so:

```
lol[42];
```

is out of bounds.